# Transversality and intersection mod.2

Tags: differential-topology

I am troubled by the following fact:

If $f,g : X\to Y$ are homotopic and both transversal to $Z$ then the mod.$2$ intersection numbers are equal $I_2(f,Z)=I_2(g(Z)$. (the book by Guillemin and Pollack, Differential Topology, page 78).

If $f,g : [-2,2]\to[-2,2]\times\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x)=(x,x^2)$ and $g(x)=(x,x^3)$ then $f$ and $g$ are homotopic (by $H(t,x)=(x,tx^3+(1-t)x^2)$) to $\Delta=\{(x,x),\ x\in[-2,2]\}$ but $I_2(f,\Delta)=2[2]=0[2]$ and $I_2(g,\Delta)=3[2]=1[2]$.

I don't know what I am missing here!
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think there might be a "closedness" (i.e. compact and no boundary) issue here but I'm not sure.

Comment: ooh this is actually really interesting.  so the proof of the statement in GP (which is definitely for *closed* manifolds) takes a homotopy between f and g which is transversal to Z. Then if you take the preimage of Z under the homotopy you get a compact 1-manifold whose boundary lies in the boundary of $X \times I$. But if $X\times I$ has boundary points not in $X\times 0 \cup X \times 1$, the 1-manifold could have boundary points on the *side* of $X\times I$ instead of just the top and bottom allowing $f$ and $g$ to have different mod 2 intersection numbers.

Comment: Sorry if this seems like mad ravings. If its not clear I'll try to clean it up into an answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I wasn't able to reply quickly! So in the Theorem we must take a closed manifold $X$ in order to get the boundary of $X\times I$ is $X\times0\cup X\times1$. Now ts clear!